# Adding three list element wise

Tags: list-manipulation, summation

I want to add n list element wise.

```
 X = {0.12229213422461696`, 0.5742532739555729`, 0.5077601317313216`, 
 0.2761709195098423};
 Y = {0.02473315107095607`, 0.6592975539333749`, 0.991980961475197`, 
 0.26414171790404234`};
```

We get
X+Y={0.147025, 1.23355, 1.49974, 0.540313}
I want to write this in code form.

Comment: Haven't you already written it in code form?

Comment: I want this for n list.

Comment: The code will not change for `n` items. The lengths of the two lists must be the same. You can `PadRight` or `PadLeft` as the case may be with zero to achieve length uniformity. OR do you have `n` lists with `m` items each?

Comment: I have code from which I am getting 10 different list I want to add them all element wise as I showed above Table[Table[Sx[ix][[j]],{ix,0,10}],{j,1,10}]

Comment: `(t = Table[Table[Sx[ix][j], {ix, 0, 10}], {j, 1, 10}]) // MatrixForm` and then `(Total[t]) // MatrixForm` ?